# Hangman game duplicates and sorting python errors

Tags: python, list, indexing, duplicates, set

I am trying to write an Hangman game in Python, which I almost figure it out for simple words but when there is a duplicate it mess up with the return indexing. Here is the code:

```
def hangman_game():  
words = ["aback", "abaft", "abandoned", "abashed", "aberrant", "abhorrent", "abiding", "abject", "ablaze", "able",
     "abnormal", "aboard", "aboriginal", "abortive", "abounding", "abrasive", "abrupt", "absent", "absorbed",
     "absorbing", "abstracted", "absurd", "abundant", "abusive", "acceptable", "accessible", "accidental",
     "accurate", "acid", "acidic", "acoustic", "acrid", "actually", "ad hoc", "adamant", "adaptable", "addicted",
     "adhesive", "adjoining", "adorable", "adventurous", "afraid", "aggressive", "agonizing", "agreeable", "ahead",
     "ajar", "alcoholic", "alert", "alike", "alive", "alleged", "alluring", "aloof", "amazing", "ambiguous",
     "ambitious", "amuck", "amused", "amusing", "ancient", "angry", "animated", "annoyed", "annoying", "anxious",
word = random.choice(words)
print(f'Random word = {word} (backtesting)')
letter_set = []
word_set = []
for i in word:
    word_set.append(i)
print(f'Letter remaining to be found ={word_set}')

while len(letter_set) < len(word_set):

    for i in word:
        letter = input("Guess a letter: ")

        if letter in word_set:
            
            letter_set.insert(word.index(letter)), letter) # issue here
            word_set.remove(letter)
            print(f'Word with letters removed: {word}')
            print(f"Letter {letter} found at word index: {word.index(letter)}")
            print(f'Letters found in word: {letter_set}')
            print(f'Word set = {word_set}')

        else:
            print(f'Letter not found in word: {word}')
print(letter_set)
print("".join(map(str, letter_set)))
```

When it find duplicates in word, it removes the letter who is a duplicate from word_set but not from word. So when it finds a word like "letter" it will insert "e" always at index[1]. So it will print like "leettr". I found out that sometimes it mess up with the index even if there are no duplicates, usually on longer words, but couldn't really figure out why.

I was thinking to make it so letter_set have a i number of "_" depending on the word by default, and than replacing it using word_set.
Any advice on how to return letter always to the right index?

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor the code a little bit. For example you can make a list `hidden_word` that will contain the same amount of `#` as letters in `word`. User will be guessing the letter and you will *reveal* the letter in hidden word untill there isn't anything left to reveal. For example:

```py
def hangman_game():
    word = "letter"  # <-- chose a random word here instead of hardcoding it

    hidden_word = list("#" * len(word))

    while "#" in hidden_word:
        print("STATUS")
        print("------")
        print(word)
        print(hidden_word)
        print("------")

        letter = input("Guess a letter: ")

        for idx, (w, h) in enumerate(zip(word, hidden_word)):
            if w == letter and h == "#":
                hidden_word[idx] = letter
                print("Letter found!")
                break
        else:
            print("Letter not found!")


hangman_game()
```

Prints:

```
STATUS
------
letter
['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
------
Guess a letter: e
Letter found!
STATUS
------
letter
['#', 'e', '#', '#', '#', '#']
------
Guess a letter: e
Letter found!
STATUS
------
letter
['#', 'e', '#', '#', 'e', '#']
------
Guess a letter: t
Letter found!
STATUS
------
letter
['#', 'e', 't', '#', 'e', '#']
------
Guess a letter: t
Letter found!
STATUS
------
letter
['#', 'e', 't', 't', 'e', '#']
------
Guess a letter: r
Letter found!
STATUS
------
letter
['#', 'e', 't', 't', 'e', 'r']
------
Guess a letter: x
Letter not found!
STATUS
------
letter
['#', 'e', 't', 't', 'e', 'r']
------
Guess a letter: l
Letter found!
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I just had no idea how to use enumerate and zip especially combined in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I copy my code here in case someone will need something similar in the future. `

`

```
def hangman_game():

new_game = input("Press enter for new game")
word = random.choice(words)
print(f'Random word = {word} (testing)')
letter_set = list("_" * len(word))
lives = 3

while "_" in letter_set:
    letter = input("Guess a letter: ").upper()
    letter_count = word.count(letter)
    if letter.isnumeric() or len(letter) > 1:
        print("Insert valid character: a-z")

    for index, (find_word, hidden) in enumerate(zip(word, letter_set)): # create new list with "_"*len(word)
        if find_word == letter.lower() and hidden == "_":               # check if letter is found in word, and if it is already revealed
            letter_set[index] = letter                                  # change "_" at the found indexes with letter
            print(f'Letter found!')
    if len(letter) > 1:
        lives += 1
        print(f"One letter at the time!  ")
    if letter.lower() not in word and letter.isnumeric() == False:
        lives -= 1
        print(f"Letter not found! Lives = {lives}")

        if lives == 0:
            print(f"YOU LOST! \n")
            hangman_game()

        if letter_count >= 1:
            letter_set[index] = letter.upper()

    print(f'Your word is: {" ".join(map(str, letter_set))}')

print("YOU WON \n")
hangman_game()

hangman_game() #wrong copied indentation
```